# How to remove hover effects on static classes?

Tags: css, sass, hover, quasar-framework

I am trying to build a toggle button similar to the ones found in quasar and am having a hard time with stacking hover effects.

I have a hover effect on all of the buttons (first and last child get their outer border rounded), but there is a different hover color when a button is active (I think). Currently they are both stacking on each other and I'm not sure how to remove the static css hover effect.

How can I removed the original hover effect and JUST have the `is-active` hover effect?

Cheers!

Here's an example of the quasar buttons:

[image]

**ButtonToggle.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="c-button-toggle-wrapper">
    <button
      :class="[option.value === selectedOption ? 'is-active' : '', 'c-button']"
      v-for="option in options"
      :key="option"
      :modelValue="modelValue"
      :option="options"
      @click="selected(option.value)"
    >
      {{ option.label }}
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
.c-button-toggle-wrapper
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  background: lavender
  width: max-content
  padding: 8px

.c-button
  background: transparent
  font-size: 14px
  font-weight: 500
  color: rgba(36, 42, 56, 0.75)
  border: none
  line-height: 1.715em
  text-transform: uppercase
  padding: 6px 16px
  margin: 0
  cursor: pointer
  &:hover
    transition: .4s
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075)
  &:first-child
    &:hover
      border-top-left-radius: 2px
      border-bottom-left-radius: 2px
  &:last-child
    &:hover
      border-top-right-radius: 2px
      border-bottom-right-radius: 2px

.is-active
  background: white
  border-radius: 4px
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16)
  border: none
  &:hover
    transition: .4s
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075)
</style>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ButtonToggle",
  props: {
    modelValue: { type: undefined, required: true },
    options: { type: Array, required: true },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selectedOption: null,
    };
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    selected(option) {
      this.selectedOption = option;
      console.log(`selectedOption`, this.selectedOption);
      this.$emit("update:modelValue", this.selectedOption);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

[**CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-easley-9eg1b?file=/src/components/ButtonToggle.vue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.not()` pseudo class.

so in your case:
`.c-button.not(.is-active):hover {...}`